# How to use small buttons on android and still show text?

Tags: android

I am designing a calculator application I need some of the "less" important buttons to be smaller. I have a LinearLayout and I have set the height of the buttons to 16dp. I have also set the font to 10sp but the text will no show if I dont wrap_content.

I have also read about that padding can be a problem and I have ensured that it is equal to zero.

Is there anyway to have a small button and still show text on it?

The code for the Button:

```
               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/SIN"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="16dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_marg"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_marg"
                   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/button_marg"
                   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_marg"
                   android:background="@drawable/keypad1"
                   android:minHeight="12dp"
                   android:minWidth="0dp"
                   android:onClick="onClick"
                   android:text="sin"
                   android:textSize="@dimen/spec_button_text_size" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `android:padding="0dp"` If not neccessary dont use margin

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem! I had set 0 padding in all directions in the background file "keypad1" but that did not help.

Comment: there is a default padding .. which take a space within the button .. thats why i changed to 0dp .. nice to know your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

reduce the text size, and for layout_width and layout_height, wrap content should work out. And you can use layout_weight attibute for buttons. Assume you have 5 buttons, if you dont specify layout_weight for them Android will automatically divide LinearLayout to 5 pieces where each button will accommodate equally, but you can specify this attribute on your own to make buttons smaller, like if you give 0.1 on 4 buttons and 0.6 for the last button.

P.S. normally the total should equals to 1 but if you want to change it also, you can specify it in your LinearLayout attribute named layout_weightSum=""